# Why can't I start a Heroku console on the Cedar stack?

Tags: heroku

Trying to debug a new Heroku deployment - seems to be missing a db table.  To do this, I'm running `heroku run console` but I get back :-

```
    Running console attached to terminal... up, run.7
sh: console: not found
```

under both my Linux and Windows environments

What have I missed to get this working?

[Very late update : this is for a Java Heroku app, not a RoR one, so anything related to rails is a little lost on me]

Comment: Downvoted? Help me ask better questions by explaining why

Answer (score 40, accepted):

on Celadon Cedar Stack it is changed to:

$ heroku run bash

Comment: Hmm that gives me a shell prompt, true enough, but I think it's a different kind of console I need.  Trying to follow the steps at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql for the "Table does not exist" problem, but the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables isn't being recognised - presumably as it's not a valid Bash command

Comment: I normally use heroku run console.

Comment: Yes I get a $ prompt, but doesn't seem to be the console.  so +1 for helpful but still not an "answer" for me.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ heroku run bash
```

then

```
…@…:/app$ script/rails console
```

It worked for me. Though the second step is specific to Ruby on Rails – I don’t know the equivalent commands for other platforms and frameworks.

Comment: Hmm, think that part may only apply to RoR apps though. I'm running a Play! framework app. Thanks for the contribution though ;)

Answer (score 4):

To run rails console, it's just:

```
heroku run rails console
```